# Hibernate not saving join column id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a ManyToOne relationship set up. Each team can have multiple users. I'm using `CascadeType.PERSIST` in Team.java as I don't want user accounts deleted when team gets removed or vice versa. Is the cascade type correct for my use case?

The join column in User.java table `team_id` stays null after saving a Team and adding a user to this team in the controller.

Team.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "memberAtTeam", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<User> usersInTeam;
```

User.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
private Team memberAtTeam;
```

TeamController.java

```
Team teamInvitedTo = invite.getTeamInvitedTo(); //Returns a Team object. Works.

teamInvitedTo.getUsersInTeam().add(invitedUser); //invitedUser is a User.java object
teamRepository.save(teamInvitedTo); //Doesn't set team_id, stays null in DB

teamInviteRepository.delete(invite); //Deletes used invite, this works.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memberAtTeam` field of `invitedUser` needs to point to `usersInTeam` when you add it to the `usersInTeam` collection of `teamInvitedTo`. Or else the foreign key column value of `usersInTeam` will not point to `teamInvitedTo`  when you save it, instead it will remain null.

```
Team teamInvitedTo = invite.getTeamInvitedTo(); //Returns a Team object. Works.
invitedUser.setMemberAtTeam(teamInvitedTo); 
teamInvitedTo.getUsersInTeam().add(invitedUser); //invitedUser is a User.java object
teamRepository.save(teamInvitedTo); //Doesn't set team_id, stays null in DB

teamInviteRepository.delete(invite); //Deletes used invite, this works.
```