# JPA @ManyToOne Cascade does not save Parent Foreign Key

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a parent class called **TimeSheet** that have a OneToMany relationShip with the child class called **TimeRecord** and the Child have a ManyToOne with Join Column.

Here are Both:

**parent**:

[image: Parent]

**child**:
[image: Child]

And as you can see, both extends from BaseEntity that only has the ID:

[image: BaseEntity]

The problem is:

Children are saved without the parent class's foreign key.

I tried putting this attribute `nullable=false` but it just throws an exception saying it cannot insert NULL.

I tried putting  CASCADE.ALL on the parent but same error occurs.

The question is, do I have to manually persist the parent and then persist the children?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate not saving join column id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71467525/hibernate-not-saving-join-column-id)